# Languages on Django CMS menu: object of type 'type' has no len()

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I've recently included English and Simplified Chinese to my project. However, when I change to my (published) **Chinese** page it throws a TypeError when using `show_menu`. The same doesn't happen in Portuguese and English

```
TypeError at /zh-cn/
object of type 'type' has no len()
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/zh-cn/
Django Version: 1.5.8
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
object of type 'type' has no len()
Exception Location: /home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menus/menu_pool.py in _mark_selected, line 171
Python Executable:  /home/marcos/django/project/env/bin/python
```

What am I doing wrong?

## Versions

Django 1.5.8

Django CMS 2.4.3

## settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (('pt', u'Português'), ('en', u'English'), ('zh-cn', u'中文'),)
CMS_LANGUAGES = LANGUAGES
```

## base.html

```
{% load sekizai_tags i18n cms_tags menu_tags %}
(...)
<div class="nav top-nav">
    <ul class="inner-nav">
    {% show_menu 0 %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

## Full Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  113.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/views.py" in details
  151.     return render_to_response(template_name, context_instance=context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
  29.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  177.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  66.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  66.     return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
  106.         return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sekizai/templatetags/sekizai_tags.py" in render_tag
  76.         rendered_contents = nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  369.         return strip_spaces_between_tags(self.nodelist.render(context).strip())
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/core.py" in render
  106.         return self.render_tag(context, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/classytags/helpers.py" in render_tag
  78.         data = self.get_context(context, **kwargs)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menus/templatetags/menu_tags.py" in get_context
  133.             nodes = menu_pool.get_nodes(request, namespace, root_id)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menus/menu_pool.py" in get_nodes
  161.         nodes = self.apply_modifiers(nodes, request, namespace, root_id, post_cut=False, breadcrumb=breadcrumb)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menus/menu_pool.py" in apply_modifiers
  149.             nodes = self._mark_selected(request, nodes)
File "/home/marcos/django/project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/menus/menu_pool.py" in _mark_selected
  171.             if node.get_absolute_url() == request.path[:len(node.get_absolute_url())]:

Exception Type: TypeError at /zh-cn/
Exception Value: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Comment: There is something wrong with one of your nodes in Menu. Try to edit by hand file `menus/menu_pool.py` in your site packages, add block `try: ... except TypeError:` around if in line 171 and print or log into file type of node, all it's attributes and what `get_absolute_url`. That will help you to narrow down what node of menu is returning something odd instead of proper URL.

Comment: It would probably best to open a ticket on our issue tracker for this: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today while retracing my steps to create a bug on the project's github I found the source of my problem.

There are some **apphooks** hanging in several pages, created when the project had only one language. I went to those pages, saved and published the draft versions and it worked!

In short:

1. Identified the apphooked pages
2. Clicked "Save and continue editing", then "Publish draft" on each
3. Restarted the server

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers and thanks for the help!